# Continuity on the left of $p\mapsto \lVert f\rVert_p$ on finite measure space.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to know why the following statement is true:

> Suppose $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $f(x)$ is a measurable function on $E$. Then for any $1<p_0<\infty$, $\lim_{p\rightarrow p_0^-}\left\Vert f\right\Vert_p=\left\Vert f\right\Vert_{p_0}$

Does anyone know why this is true?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as saying that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\lVert f\rVert_{p_n}=\lVert f\rVert_{p_0}$ for all increasing sequences $p_1,p_2,\cdots$ such that $p_n\to p_0$. $$\int_E \lvert f\rvert^{p_n}\,d\mu=\int_E 1_{\{\lvert f\rvert< 1\}}\lvert f\rvert^{p_n}\,d\mu+\int_E 1_{\{\lvert f\rvert\ge1\}}\lvert f\rvert^{p_n}\,d\mu$$

The first term converges to $\int_E 1_{\{\lvert f\rvert< 1\}}\lvert f\rvert^{p_0}\,d\mu$ because the integrand is dominated by $1_{\{\lvert f\rvert< 1\}}$. The integrands in the second term are an increasing sequence of positive functions, therefore the integrals converge to $\int_E1_{\{\lvert f\rvert\ge 1\}} \lvert f\rvert^{p_0}\,d\mu$ by Beppo Levi. Summing everything up, $\lVert f\rVert_{p_n}^{p_n}\to \lVert f\rVert_{p_0}^{p_0}$ and therefore $$\lVert f\rVert_{p_n}=(\lVert f\rVert_{p_n}^{p_n})^{1/p_n}=((\lVert f\rVert_{p_n}^{p_n})^{p_0/p_n})^{1/p_0}\to ((\lVert f\rVert_{p_0}^{p_0})^1)^{1/p_0}=\lVert f\rVert_{p_0}$$

Because the map $(0,\infty)\times \left[\frac1{p_0},2\right]\to [0,\infty)$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto x^y$ extends continuously to a map $[0,\infty]\times \left[\frac1{p_0},2\right]\to [0,\infty]$ by setting $0^y=0$ and $\infty^y=\infty$ for all $y$.